# modify Shor’s quantum order finding algorithm in such a way that it uses as few qubits as possible

Tags: quantum-gate, shors-algorithm, quantum-fourier-transform

I am supposed to modify Shor’s quantum order finding algorithm in such a way that it uses as few qubits as possible.

Beforehand, I already did an exercise where I showed that the inverse Quantum Fourier Transform can also be rewritten such that the circuit no longer uses any two-qubit gates (only H, $R_s$ or $R_s ^\dagger$ gates). I did that by using the measurement outcomes as the control part. The exercise is supposed to build on that but I don't really see how..

Does anyone have an idea?